# Numerical integration of given points, simple/easy way

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I have the `x` and the `f(x)` for a set of `x`. I don't know the function, actually. This is sufficient to integrate it?

The `x` value might span from `1` to no more than `50`, usually around `10`. While `y` is always negative and it's peak might pass `-100`.

What's the simplest approach?

```
x 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 9
y 0 -3 -5 -7 -5 -3 -2 -1 -1 0
```

May I ask the Python code com compute that?

Comment: what is $y$ ? You have a set $$\{(x_i,f(x_i)\}$$?

Comment: Between the points $x_{i}$, $f(x)$ is interpolated with whatever method you choose. So you will get an approximation to the integral.

Comment: Cross-post with [scicomp.stackexchange](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/25831/numerical-integration-of-given-points-simple-easy-way).